# How to clear RTCPeerConnection (WebRTC)?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, domexception

Has anyone seen that error, literally:

"**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Cannot create so many PeerConnections**"?

I guess it's happens because I didn't removed connections (maybe not, maybe it's because I didn't provide more memory or something). But from where? Where do they accumulate?

I didn't found answer for the question, literally, nowhere.

I was tried to solve that problem a couple days. By the way, no such thing as a stupid question, right?

UPD: Forgot to add that I using sip.js library.

Comment: Without a bit more code is difficult to guess where the error may be. There is an answer related to maximum number of RTCPeerConnections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194545/maximum-number-of-rtcpeerconnection/41205991#41205991

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum number of RTCPeerConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194545/maximum-number-of-rtcpeerconnection)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found and fixed the problem. Sip.js library has a `.close()` method that closes the `peerConnection`. But this is not enough for a garbage collector. Object `peerConnection` should be reset to `null`.

So, the solving was adding two new lines in library, like

> this.mediaHandler.peerConnection = null

and that's it. WebRTC is not crowded and all are happy.