# WebRTC, WRONG Active/Unactive RTCPeerConnection Limit

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, limit

I reached a problem quite annoying today with the Number of WebRTC connections available on a single web page. 
See this simple test that is the experimental proof of this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205991/6126329).

This code will fail with 256 connections on Chrome and will run forever (wanted feature for the test) on Firefox.

```js
var Peer = window.SimplePeer
var peer1, peer2
numberofconnection = 0

function connect() {
  peer1 = new Peer({ initiator: true })
  peer2 = new Peer()

  peer1.on('signal', function (data) {
    // when peer1 has signaling data, give it to peer2 somehow
    peer2.signal(data)
  })

  peer2.on('signal', function (data) {
    // when peer2 has signaling data, give it to peer1 somehow
    peer1.signal(data)
  })

  peer1.on('connect', function () {
    numberofconnection++
    console.log('connection number: ', numberofconnection)
    // wait for 'connect' event before using the data channel
    peer1.send('hey peer2, how is it going?')
  })

  peer2.on('data', function (data) {
    // got a data channel message
    console.log('got a message')
    destroy()
  })
}

function destroy() {
  let check = () => peer1 === null && peer2 ===null
  let done = () => { connect() }
  peer1.on('close', () => {
    peer1.removeAllListeners()
    peer1 = null
    if(check()) done()
  })
  peer2.on('close', () => {
    peer2.removeAllListeners()
    peer2 = null
    if(check()) done()
  })
  peer1.destroy()
  peer2.destroy()
}

connect()
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-peer/9.0.0/simplepeer.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently, 256 is the limit. But in my test I only have 2 active sockets at a time!!

- Go to chrome://webrtc-internals/ in Chrome to see all active and
  closed connections and run the script.
- Go to about:webrtc in Firefox    to see active connection and run the
  script, you will see only 2    active connections.

Now is the time for my question: why Chrome limits the number of dead connection? It is normal or a bug to report? Because if this is a wanted feature, you cannot create a webrtc network with a changing topology in Chrome.

**Edit:**

For more precision, the error reached is: **"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Cannot create so many PeerConnections"** which occures only on Chrome with only 2 active connections. Imagine now, you have a manager which recreate connections when needed, for example in a DHT context, if you let your web page open for a long time you will reach this error. Even when you are completely closing dead connections.